# CSS puzzle : absolute position of table title

Tags: html, css

### HTML structure

I've got the following html structure: **This is a fixed structure that I can't edit**

```
<div class="separator"></div>

<table class="myClass">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title1</th>
            <th>title2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ...
</table>

<div class="separator"></div>
```

---

### CSS

The first and last div are separators whose css is:

```
.separator {
   height: 20px;
   background-color: gray;
}
```

**Note that separators are complex widgets and not only design (I've intentionnaly simplified the example)**

---

### The problem

I want to position the table header **before** the first separator but the table body must remain between the two separators.

---

### What I have tried

1. Here is the initial jsfiddle for testing:
   http://jsfiddle.net/prhgW/1/
2. I've tried to position absolute the thead tag and use negative top
   values but when doing so, the width of the thead is smaller than
   100% of the table and so column titles are misplaced regarding the
   column value. the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/prhgW/2/
3. I've also tried to put the width at 100% but the tr tag do not
   follow that rules : http://jsfiddle.net/prhgW/3/

---

### Additional rules

- I would like to avoid fixed width/height of the table or any element (so, absolute positioning everything is not acceptable solution)
- I would like cross browser compatibility
- avoid javascript fix (pure css would be better)

Comment: If you give a fixed width to `<tr>` first children it behaves like you wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/prhgW/9/ But is it OK to use a fixed width in your case?

Comment: No, I can't use fixed width or height. I can use percentage but that's all.

Comment: Is it okay to use jquery/javascript in your case? Otherwise i don't think your going to get the width of the two top th tags to be the same as the td of the table below it

Comment: If I can, I would like to avoid javascript (pure css would be ideal) and as you pointed it, I need to have the same width for th tags and the corresponding td tags

Comment: Is it an option? http://jsfiddle.net/8BvHT/

Comment: Not really because I've intentionally simplified the example. But in reality the "separators" are real widgets (pager in fact) and not only for design purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this applicable to your problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/prhgW/16/

I added some space beneath the `<th>` and shifted the first separator down. This works if you know the height of the separator AND the `<th>`.

Comment: Yes ! This one is applicable ;) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Note that this *won't* work if there are `.separator`s preceding the `.myClass` table, as the *first* `.separator` is targeted which is assumed to precede the table.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I assumed the problem is the shifting of the separator and not the selection of it. But yes, this **might** be a problem if there is no further option to distinguish the separators and the placement is not fixed.

Comment: @Christoph Well, I didn't make that assumption for my answer which led to a whole range of... well, "interesting" problems. Of course, if selecting the `.separator` in front of the table is not a problem, your solution will work just fine.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens well, in the end I think it doesn't matter much, since or solutions are pretty much the same, so i gave you +1;)

Comment: @Christoph Agreed. You push the separator down, I push the table up. It's all about what you can assume about the markup.

Comment: yes, both solutions are quite similar and I've adapted a mix of both for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I've been toying with this in pure CSS, here's my [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/RVkgD/).

Basically, I use the immediate sibling combinator `.separator + .myClass` to target the table following the separator. I then move the whole table up so the headers line up just above the separator. This move is compensated with an identical `margin-bottom` so the content below the table neatly follows the table. Finally, I put some padding on the header cells in `thead` to push `tbody` below the separator.

Possible caveats:

- The separator height needs to be fixed and known. This is probably not too much of a problem.
- The height of the headings needs to be fixed and known. I used `1em` as default.
- If there is content right above the separator, it may be overlapped by the table. This is inherent to the problem: you can't conditionally apply more padding to the separator. You *can* target a table following a separator, but you *can't* target a separator which is followed by a table. The sibling combinator only works for elements following a previous sibling, not the other way around.

Comment: +1 yes, this is also an accepted solution but Christoph has answered few minutes before you ;)

Comment: Damn ninjas! Ah well, it was fun messing with CSS again. :P

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a gray line below the Table title and below the last row, you can use css border property to set the style as in here

http://jsfiddle.net/vzGtF/

I have removed the seperator class and the div using the classes.

Hope the helps.

Comment: like I've said in comments of my post, separators are in fact more complex widgets (I've intentionally simplified the example) and not only design. This solution cannot be used.

Comment: Would the widget (seperator) sit between the table title and the table body? This is what I conclude after seeing the fiddle update 2 & 3. I might be wrong.

Comment: In order: title, separator, body. the problem is that my html structure is fixed and all must be done using only css...

Answer (score 0):

I used a little bit of jquery to append a row below the titles of your table.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.myClass thead').append('<tr><td class="separator" colspan=2></td><tr>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: as I said before, separator is not only a class but a complex widget. Moreover, I would like to avoid javascript to fix this problem.